# What is the performance difference between accumulator and collect() in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

Accumulator are basically the shared variable in spark to be updated by executors but read by driver only.
`Collect()` in spark is to get all the data into the driver from executors.

So, in both when I am get the data ultimately in driver only. so, what is the difference in performance when we use accumulator or `collect()` to convert a large RDD into a LIST?

Code to convert dataframe to List using accumulator

```
val queryOutput = spark.sql(query)
val acc = spark.sparkContext.collectionAccumulator[Map[String,Any]]("JsonCollector")
val jsonString = queryOutput.foreach(a=>acc.add(convertRowToJSON(a)))
acc.value.asScala.toList


def convertRowToJSON(row: Row): Map[String,Any] = {
    val m = row.getValuesMap(row.schema.fieldNames)
    println(m)
    JSONObject(m).obj
  }
```

Code to convert dataframe to list using collect()

```
val queryOutput = spark.sql(query)
queryOutput.toJSON.collectAsList()
```

Comment: can you add your code for accumulator

Comment: I have updated the original question with code.

Answer (score 0):

> Convert large RDD to LIST

It is not a good idea. collect will move data from all executors to driver memory. If memory is not enough then it will throw Out Of Memory (OOM) Exception. If your data is fits in memory of single machine then probably you don't need spark.

Spark natively supports accumulators of numeric types, and programmers can add support for new types. They can be used to implement counters (as in MapReduce) or sums. OUT parameter of accumulator should be a type that can be read atomically (e.g., Int, Long), or thread-safely (e.g., synchronized collections) because it will be read from other threads.

CollectionAccumulator `.value` returns List (ArrayList implementation) and it will throw OOM if size is greater than driver memory.

Comment: We can convert data from large RDD to list using accumulator as I have already did. Only thing I didn't get that how collect() gave OOM issues but accumulator didn't.

Comment: @KaranManchanda: Can you add that to the question? I.e. the code you used with an accumulator that worked. That would make analysing the difference easier.