# How to utilize all Driver cores in cluster mode in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I've an RDD **final_rdd** which I am collecting on driver using the accumulator and converting to List.

```
  val acumFileKeys = sc.collectionAccumulator[String]("File Keys")
  var input_map_keys = ListBuffer(input_map.keys.toSeq: _*)

  final_rdd.keys.foreach(m => acumFileKeys.add(m.trim))
  import collection.JavaConverters._
  acumFileKeys.value.asScala.toList.foreach(fileKey => { // code goes here })
```

The foreach loop runs on driver and uses only 1 core out of 5 cores. Which in turn results in slow performance. Is there any way I can utilise all cores of driver.
Below is the spark-submit command. We have total 5 workers 5 cores each and each having 16G memory.

```
spark-submit --class com.test.MyMainClass \
             --deploy-mode cluster \
             --master spark://master_ip:7077 \
             --executor-cores 5 \
             --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=5G \
             --conf spark.network.timeout=800s \
             --executor-memory 8g \
             --driver-memory 8g \
             /opt/jars/my_app.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Scala Parallel Collections - https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/configuration.html

```
val list = acumFileKeys.value.asScala.toList
import scala.collection.parallel._
val forkJoinPool = new scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool(5)

val parallelList = list.par
parallelList.tasksupport = new ForkJoinTaskSupport(forkJoinPool)

parallelList.foreach { case fileKey =>
  println(Thread.currentThread.getName)
  ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I've tried list.par.foreach but final result was not same as list.foreach. How ForkJoinTaskSupport can help?

Comment: ForkJoinTaskSupport helps us in defining a threadpool of size 5. your processing code in foreach should be threadsafe... then only you can utilize parallelism.

Comment: ALIVE 5 (5 Used) 20.0 GB (8.0 GB Used)
ALIVE 5 (1 Used) 20.0 GB (8.0 GB Used) ALIVE 5 (5 Used) 20.0 GB (8.0 GB Used)  Still the driver is using 1 core only.

Answer (score 0):

First, `final_rdd.keys.foreach` is not a for-loop. `foreach` in this context is an operation on `rdd` which is performed remotely. It's already parallelized.

Usually there is no much sense in utilizing computing resources of the driver. In typical workflow the driver is mostly underloaded and just coordinates computations that happens on workers.

In your particular case the code could be rewritten as `final_rdd.keys.collect()`.

Comment: I am doing the collect itself but using the accumulator since it performs faster. Here my aim is to iterate the list, which is already collected on driver, in parallel.

Comment: Do you have an evidence that accumulator works faster than `collect`? As per my understanding of how both work `collect` should be at least not slower.

Comment: I don't have evidence, you may please visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57799402/what-is-the-performance-difference-between-accumulator-and-collect-in-spark and answer if you have a better understanding.